# MySQL query values don't pass to ejs file. Query depends on results of prior query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a dynamic survey. They survey questions are pulled from a database given a survey's GUID. Then the answers to be used for each question are pulled from the database given the questionGUID of each question pulled from the query above.  I can't seem to get the question answer values to pass into my ejs file.

I think it has to do with the asynchrounous nature of the query functions, but I've tried multiple solutions I found on here.on.

My route.js

```
function router() {
  // survey start page
  surveyRouter.get('/', function(req, res){
    var prms = req.query;
    res.render('surveyIndex', {prms:prms})
  });

  surveyRouter.get('/:surveyGuid', function(req, res){
    //empty array to put values in
      var questionValues = [];
      function storeQuestionValues(rows){
          questionValues= rows[0];
      // console.log(questionValues); 
      }

    //surveyGUID hard coded into HTML link href
    //gets questions to use in ejs
    connection.query("CALL spGetSurveyQuestions(?);", req.params.surveyGuid, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if(err) throw err;

      //all questions
      var questions = rows[0]

      questions.forEach(function(question){
        //push results of stored procedure that gets question values by question GUID into empty array
        connection.query("CALL spGetSurveyQuestionValues(?);", question.QuestionGuid, (err, rows, fields) => {
          storeQuestionValues(rows);
          // console.log(questionValues);  
        });
      });  
      res.render('test', {questions : questions, questionValues : questionValues });
    });
  });

  return surveyRouter;
}
```

my testing ejs file

```
  <%include partials/header%>

<div id="masthead" class="container">
      <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class=text-center> Satisfaction Survey</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<form>
  <div class="containter">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%questions.forEach(function(question){%>
        <label><%= question.QustionSequence %>. <%= question.QuestionText %> </label></br>
          <% questionValues.forEach(function(questionValue){%>
           <p> <%= questionValue.AnswerText%></p>
            <%});%>
        <%});%>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


<%include partials/footer%>
```

I get header errors if I move the res.render() into the second query function, but the question values for the first question appear under each question. So at least it spits something out there.

Right now I am just trying to get anything to print under each question from the question values query, and worry about what values go with what question later.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make progress by taking some time away and coming up with something a bit more clever.

```
  surveyRouter.get('/:surveyGuid/:questionSequence', function(req, res){
    var questionSequence = req.params.questionSequence;
    connection.query("CALL spGetSurveyQuestions(?);", req.params.surveyGuid, (err, results, fields) =>{
      var questions = results[0];
      if(questions[questionSequence - 1].QustionSequence == questionSequence){
        connection.query("CALL spGetSurveyQuestionValues(?);", questions[questionSequence - 1].QuestionGuid, (err, results, fields) =>{
          var questionValues = results[0];
          res.render('test', {questions: questions, questionSequence: questionSequence, questionValues: questionValues});
        });
      }
    });
  });
```